# Prove that $[0,\frac{1}{2}]\ni x\mapsto 2x\in [0,1]$ is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, connectedness, path-connected

> Let $S$ be a topological space.
> Let $f$ be a continuous mapping from the topological subspace $[0,1]$ of $\mathbb{R}$ to $S$.
> Let $f_1$ be the mapping from the topological subspace $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ of $\mathbb{R}$ to $S$ such that $f_1(x):=f(2x)$.
> Prove that $f_1$ is a continuous mapping from the topological subspace $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ of $\mathbb{R}$ to $S$.

My solution is here:

> Let $g$ be a mapping from the topological subspace $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ of $\mathbb{R}$ to the topological subspace $[0,1]$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x)=2x$.
> Then, $f_1=f\circ g$.
> Since $f$ is continuous, we need only to prove $g$ is continuous.
> We need to prove if $O'$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then $g^{-1}([0,1]\cap O')$ is open in the topological subspace $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ of $\mathbb{R}$.
> $g^{-1}([0,1]\cap O')$ is open in the topological subspace $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ of $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if there is an open subset $O$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $g^{-1}([0,1]\cap O')=[0,\frac{1}{2}]\cap O$.
>
> Let $g_1$ be a mapping from the topological space $\mathbb{R}$ to the topological space $\mathbb{R}$ such that $g_1(x):=2x$.
> Then, $g_1$ is a continuous mapping.
> Proof:
> Let $O'$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$.
> Then, $g_1^{-1}(O')=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid 2x\in O'\}$.
> Let $x_0\in g_1^{-1}(O')$.
> Then, $2x_0\in O'$.
> Since $O'$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, there exists a positive real number $\epsilon$ such that $(2x_0-\epsilon,2x_0+\epsilon)\subset O'$.
> Let $x\in (x_0-\frac{\epsilon}{2},x_0+\frac{\epsilon}{2})$.
> Then, $x_0-\frac{\epsilon}{2}<x<x_0+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ holds.
> So, $2x_0-\epsilon<2x<2x_0+\epsilon$ holds.
> So, $2x\in (2x_0-\epsilon,2x_0+\epsilon)\subset O'$.
> So, $x\in g_1^{-1}(O')$.
> Therefore, $(x_0-\frac{\epsilon}{2},x_0+\frac{\epsilon}{2})\subset g_1^{-1}(O')$.
> So, $g_1^{-1}(O')$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$.
> So, $g_1$ is a continuous mapping.
>
> Let $O'$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$.
> Then, $g^{-1}([0,1]\cap O')=[0,\frac{1}{2}]\cap g_1^{-1}(O')$ holds.
> Proof:
> Let $x_0\in g^{-1}([0,1]\cap O')$.
> Then, $x_0\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ since the domain of $g$ is $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$.
> Since $g(x)=g_1(x)$ on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$, $g_1(x_0)=g(x_0)\in O'$.
> So, $x_0\in g_1^{-1}(O')$.
> So, $g^{-1}([0,1]\cap O')\subset [0,\frac{1}{2}]\cap g_1^{-1}(O')$.
>
> Let $x_0\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]\cap g_1^{-1}(O')$.
> Then, $g(x_0)\in [0,1]$ since the codomain of $g$ is $[0,1]$.
> Since $g(x)=g_1(x)$ on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$, $g(x_0)=g_1(x_0)\in O'$.
> So, $x_0\in g^{-1}([0,1]\cap O')$.
>
> Since $g_1^{-1}(O')$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$, $g^{-1}([0,1]\cap O')=[0,\frac{1}{2}]\cap g_1^{-1}(O')$ is open in the topological subspace of $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ of $\mathbb{R}$.

I guess my solution is unnecessarily long.
Please give me a better solution.

Comment: Can't you use the theorem that says that a composition of continuous functions is continuous?

Comment: @uniquesolution He did when writing "$f_1=f\circ g$.  
Since $f$ is continuous, we need only to prove $g$ is continuous. "

Comment: You can shorten a little the proof that $g_1$ is continuous, by avoiding to talk about open subsets and simply prove that  $g_1$ is continuous at any $x_0\in\Bbb R$ (i.e. just keep your traditional $\epsilon-\delta$ argument).

Comment: You can avoid to repeat frequently "topological subspace ... of ..." E.g. Just say "Define $g:[0,1/2]\to[0,1]$ by $g(x)=2x$".

Comment: @uniquesolution Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: Once you know that $g_1$ is continuous, so is $g_1\circ i,$ where $i:[0,1/2]\to\Bbb R,\;x\mapsto x$ is continuous (by definition of the subspace topology on $[0,1/2]$).

Comment: I agree with @Anne Bauval, but I also think a more general point of view is helpful: by this I mean that you should prove for yourself that in general linear functions between euclidean spaces are continuous (or at least functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, maybe using your knowledge of analysis), and that restrictions of continuous functions are continuous. This is not difficult to prove and is conceptually important, and since you will need it often it is better to have it in your "baggage of known facts".

Comment: I completely agree with @milore. But since I was in the course of peeling that pedestrian proof, a last word: once you know that $g_1\circ i:[0,1/2]\to\Bbb R$ is continuous, to deduce that $g:[0,1/2]\to[0,1]$ also is, just notice that for any open subset $O$ of $\Bbb R,$ $g^{-1}(O\cap[0,1])=(g\circ i)^{-1}(O).$

Comment: Sorry, I skipped the subscript at the end: I meant $(g_1\circ i)^{-1}(O).$

Comment: @milore Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your solution is unnecessarily long. A shorter solution is, for example, this: Let $g:[0,\frac{1}{2}]\to [0,1]$ be the map defined by $g(x)=2x$. The map $g$ is obviously continuous. Since $f_1=f\circ g$, and since $f$ is continuous by hypothesis, it follows that the composition $f_1=f\circ g$ is also continuous.

Comment: I agree that the OP's solution is unnecessarily long, but you cannot just say that $g$ is obviously continuous. If you read the question (and the comments), you will see that most of his work went into proving just that: he may have been a little verbose and unsophisticated (we addressed that in the comments), but if he felt the need to prove that fact, then it wasn't obvious to him. I believe for someone who is just starting to learn topology this is fair (maybe whoever taught them analysis didn't stress enough the topological aspect of continuity).